# Reactstrap and aligning items in Container

Tags: reactjs, reactstrap

I was creating a Weather app in ReactJS and I'm encountering some problem with aligning certain items

[image]

```
<Container>
    <Row>
        <Col sm="12" md={{ size: 12, offset: 2 }}>
            <Card style={card}>
                <CardImg src="./assets/images/sunny.jpg" alt="Card image cap" />
                <CardImgOverlay>
                    <CardHeader>
                        <Row>
                            <Col sm="12" md={{size: 12, offset: 5 }}>
                                <div className='text'>Place</div>
                            </Col>
                        </Row>
                        <Row>
                            <Col sm="12" md={{size: 12, offset: 5 }}>
                                <div className='text'>Date</div>
                            </Col>
                        </Row>
                    </CardHeader>
                    <CardBody>
                        <Row>
                            <Col sm="12" md={{ size: 12 }}>
                                <LocalForm onSubmit={(values) => this.handleSubmit(values)}>
                                    <Control.text model='.place' type='place' className='search' id='place' placeholder={this.state.place}/>
                                    <button type='submit' className='button text-small'>Search</button>
                                </LocalForm>
                            </Col>
                            </Row>
                    </CardBody>
                         .
                         .
```

So as you can see I'm using `offset` in `Col` to centralize some of the components but it's not getting the job done perfectly as there are clearly some faults in it.

My question is:

- Is it possible to align elements in a  Col perfectly without using offset?
- Also is it possible to remove this weird grey-ish background of CardHeader?

Comment: What library are the styling components coming from? Or are you doing your own CSS?

Comment: I'm using reactstrap and some custom CSS for styling text.

Comment: Ah, so this is a bootstrap question and not a react question. Remember react does not do layout by itself. You might want to retag and edit so more qualified people might answer.